# Default transparency with GeoServer layer groups with overlapping raster layers

Tags: raster, geoserver, transparency-opacity

I have deployed two pan-sharpened raster from Pleiades imagery covering different areas with an overlap. Individually they are opaque (see [here](https://ifl.francophonelibre.org/llg/Pleiades_Dakar/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=Pleiades_Dakar:SN_Dakar_Pleiades_IMG_PHR1B_PANSHARP_201704031153401_ORT_2353881101&styles=&bbox=-17.4355972222222,14.7282824074074,-17.349870370370347,14.8079074074074&width=768&height=713&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers) and [there](https://ifl.francophonelibre.org/llg/Pleiades_Dakar/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=Pleiades_Dakar:SN_Dakar_Pleiades_IMG_PHR1B_PANSHARP_201703291142565_ORT_2353882101&styles=&bbox=-17.3916527777778,14.672203703703737,-17.20175925925928,14.8277916666667&width=768&height=629&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers)) but when inside a layer group (with default settings), they turn approx 50% transparent and it seems there is nothing you can change (see [here](https://ifl.francophonelibre.org/llg/Pleiades_Dakar/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=Pleiades_Dakar:Pleiades_Dakar_2017&styles=&bbox=-17.4355972222222,14.672203703703737,-17.20175925925928,14.8277916666667&width=768&height=511&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers)). If alone in another layer group the raster are displayed without transparency (see [there](https://ifl.francophonelibre.org/llg/Pleiades_Dakar/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=Pleiades_Dakar:Pleiades_Dakar_test_only1&styles=&bbox=-17.3916527777778,14.672203703703737,-17.20175925925928,14.8277916666667&width=768&height=629&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers)). It seems this is a because there is a overlap. Is there a way to solve this in GeoServer or is it mandatory to cut the imagery in order to have no overlap at all?

EDIT : adding a screenshot of one of the layers settings:
[image: screenshot]

and another screenshot regarding the layer group settings:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Please add screen shots rather than live links, we also need to know how you have styled your rasters.

Comment: Thanks for your answers Ian. Basically what I described IS what I have done: two raster as layers in GeoServer and a layers group with he two layers together, what my links point to. I thought it was better to show them this way than with screenshots in order to allow zooming in and out. I have not styled these raster, the settings are default. Based on this, I rephrase a bit my question: is there something to be set in GeoServer to solve this default transparency, or do I need to do something on the raster themselves (I suggested to cut them in order not to have any overlapping) ?

Comment: I figured out you were talking about settings screenshots, my bad. I edited the question and add two, if other ones would be helpful, just tell me.

Comment: Actually, I meant the maps them selves but never mind. What styles are you using? Have you considered using an image mosaic rather than a layer group which was not really designed for this